# How can i add a common "C" Wire to this old system?

Tags: hvac

I have an oil HVAC that was put in back in 1996. I sadly do not know the model of the furnace and cannot dig out any paperwork on it.  Anyways, i want to go with some of the bells and whistles for a thermostat which needs the wire. I took off the cover and i did not see anything like the pictures i have found online nor could i find a transformer people spoke of. Maybe it is just that old?  Anyways, here are the pictures from the inside.

[Bottom Panel http://imageshack.com/a/img538/4057/CZfxrA.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img538/4057/CZfxrA.jpg)
[Tstat wires http://imageshack.com/a/img661/1037/6qklHB.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img661/1037/6qklHB.jpg)
[Wiring Diagram http://imageshack.com/a/img912/9646/DoAYY7.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img912/9646/DoAYY7.jpg)

Comment: There has to be a transformer, otherwise it wouldn't say 24VAC. From the diagram, I'm guessing it's in/on the Primary Control board. You've got a white going in that looks like 120V, and two thermostat connections going out at 24V.

Comment: Note the thermostat connections aren't differentiated by which is the ground, so you'll need to do more research on that control board to trace those, and you'll likely be wiring things without a terminal screw if you really want this thermostat. Another option to consider is adding an external transformer just for your thermostat.

Answer (score 1):

The transformer in this model is in the Oil Burner Primary Control. It does not look like there is a terminal to add a C wire. You're out of luck, bub.

From the manual: https://customer.honeywell.com/resources/techlit/TechLitDocuments/69-0000s/69-0617.pdf

[image]

Comment: Is there a different Oil Burner Primary Control i should replace it with that would provide such things? Something that may be inexpensive but still work?

Comment: Not worth it. It would be cheaper and easier to put in a dedicated transformer for the thermostat.

Comment: Can i use a simple AC transformer like this one?  http://www.amazon.com/24V40AC-24V-40VA-Transformer-Input/dp/B00MAKCNM6/ref=sr_1_8?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1419459258&sr=1-8&keywords=24v . I do see some people use this, which i hate to cut the cables as i rather just have the screws on the transformer: http://www.amazon.com/LockState-Connect-LS-24VAC-Adaptor-LS-90i/dp/B0071IWJ7G/ref=pd_bxgy_hi_text_y#customerReviews.  The difference between the two is simply the MA rating.

Comment: The first one should be fine. Thermostats don't take much power. Just make sure you hook it up so that the common from your transformer is not the same as the common for the wire going back to your furnace. If you tell me what model thermostat you are using and I can find the manual for it, then I can recommend how to hook it up.

Comment: I plan to use the NEST Thermostat.  According to others, I would use W1 and RH for the heat. I then should hook this extra wire up to to C and RC. Someone on the NEST forums did reconmend that the Top T line and the bottom F line would be opposite sides of the transformer therefore making the bottom F as the C wire. I have yet to take a voltage meeter out for it.

Comment: Exactly. Proceed!